# Intuition behind variance in terms of $L^P$ norms?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I've just started working through Varadhan's Probability lecture notes, and I was wondering if there's any intuitive connection between the variance formula and Holder's inequality/ $L^p$ norms in general.

In a sense, for a probability space $(\Omega, \cal B, P)$ with $P(\Omega) = 1$ and a random variable  $X\in L^2(\Omega)$, then if $X\geq 0$ we can write:

$E[X^2] - (E[X])^2 = (\int X(w)^2 dP) - (\int X(w) dP)^2 = \vert\vert X \vert\vert^2_{L^2(\Omega)} - \vert\vert X^{\frac{1}{2}} \vert\vert^4_{L^{2}(\Omega)}\geq 0 $

Is there any way to think of variance in terms of the $L^p$ norms? It's probably not a very good question, but I was hoping to make a connection between this and my Lebesgue integration/measure theory course I just finished.

Comment: I just wish to make a comment.  Nice user name given your topic and just finished course.

Answer (score 3):

The even $p$ norms corresponds directly to the $p$th moment of the random variable.
         $$E[X^p] = ||X||_p^p$$
The association for odd $p$ is not as clear because the definition of the norm requires taking the absolute value of the outcomes.  At best you can note:
         $$E[|X|^p] = ||X||_p^p$$
In this way, for a symmetric distribution, you can essentially say its characteristic function is defined by the norms of a random variable with that distribution.  For a random variable that is non-negative, as you mentioned, all the norms give the characteristic function.